# Should I mount the procfs on a FreeBSD server?

Tags: freebsd, linux

The [procfs manpage](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=procfs&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE&format=html) states that `procfs` is required for the complete operation of programs such as `ps` and `w`. I want to mount it but wonder if there are any security implications of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically standard in the linux world..

I would assume for that reason, you have not to worry about security implications for this particular question..

What do you expect a security implication could be???

/proc maintains and shows simply an open heart to the kernel and process's

Note: i just "quickly" checked online ( yes i have the internet :P ), and found 2 security problems from 2000 & 2005 for BSD variants... However im sure they are fixed

Answer (score 1):

In my experience in FreeBSD you'll only need to use procfs when you use Linux binary application.

You can check [this article on FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/linux-users/procfs.html) , hope it helps.

Comment: `ps -e` requires procfs